# How to pass variable from Flask app to Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I know this has been asked probably asked before but for some reason it is not working for me.
Code:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.templating import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'mysecret'
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

@app.route("/")
def index():
    items = ["backpack", "handbag", "laptop"]
    return render_template("index.html", items=items)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = 'mysecret'
    app.run(debug = True)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" {{ url_for('static', filename='app.js')}}></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = '{{ items }}'
        myFunc(data)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dvTable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
function myFunc(data) {
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = 'Item';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = data[i];
    }
    var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
        dvTable.innerHTML = "";
        dvTable.appendChild(table);
}
```

This is not returning anything on the screen. There are no exceptions. Please tell me what's the issue here?

Comment: You need to pass a JSON object. Parse `items` in json string and then create a js object  with `var data = JSON.parse( /* your JSON string from python */)`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the variable within jinja2 into a json object using the built-in filter [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson).

`var data = {{ items | tojson }}`

---

When executing a javascript function which is to change DOM elements, it is important to ensure that these are already loaded. One possibility is the listener used in my example. Another possibility is to put the script tags at the end of the file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(items) {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          myFunc(items);
        });
      })({{ items | tojson }});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dvTable"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Hi, I've tried this as well. This shows error in VSCode IDE. On adding it within quotes, there's the same problem as I've mentioned in the post.

Comment: @SatashreeRoy I have revised my answer and hope that I could help you.